# How to host NServiceBus in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, nservicebus, publish-subscribe

I recently upgraded from NServiceBus 5x to 6.0.0-beta0004 to be able to host a ASP.NET Core application (whose main function is to listen to NServiceBus messages). I'm having problems with the startup of the host as the endpoint doesn't seem to subscribe to the publisher.

I am using the [pubsub](https://github.com/Particular/docs.particular.net/tree/master/samples/pubsub/Core_6) example to fix the problem. Apart from the projects that are in there by default, I added one extra project, a fresh ASP.NET Core project (based on the full .NET framework). I tried to use the exact same NServiceBus configuration, but instead of using the app/web.config, I am using the following configuration:

```
public class ConfigurationSource : IConfigurationSource
{
    public T GetConfiguration<T>() where T : class, new()
    {
        UnicastBusConfig config = new UnicastBusConfig()
        {
            MessageEndpointMappings = new MessageEndpointMappingCollection()
        };

        var endpointMapping = new MessageEndpointMapping
        {
            AssemblyName = "Shared",
            Endpoint = "Samples.PubSub.MyPublisher"
        };
        config.MessageEndpointMappings.Add(endpointMapping);
        return config as T;
    }
}
```

The Startup class was extended with the following code:

```
public IConfigurationRoot Configuration
{
    get;
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddSingleton(this.GetBus());
}
private IEndpointInstance GetBus()
{
    LogManager.Use<DefaultFactory> ().Level(NServiceBus.Logging.LogLevel.Info);
    var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration("Samples.PubSub.Subscriber3");
    endpointConfiguration.UseSerialization<JsonSerializer>();
    endpointConfiguration.DisableFeature<AutoSubscribe>();
    endpointConfiguration.UsePersistence<InMemoryPersistence>();
    endpointConfiguration.SendFailedMessagesTo("error");
    endpointConfiguration.EnableInstallers();
    // Skip web.config settings and use programmatic approach
    endpointConfiguration.CustomConfigurationSource(new ConfigurationSource());
    var endpointInstance = Endpoint.Start(endpointConfiguration).Result;
    endpointInstance.Subscribe<IMyEvent>().Wait();
    return endpointInstance;
}
```

The Message Handler is identical to the other Subscriber projects in the solution:

```
public class EventMessageHandler : IHandleMessages<IMyEvent>
{
    static ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger<EventMessageHandler>();

    public Task Handle(IMyEvent message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
    {
        log.Info($"Subscriber 2 received IEvent with Id {message.EventId}.");
        log.Info($"Message time: {message.Time}.");
        log.Info($"Message duration: {message.Duration}.");
        return Task.FromResult(0);
   }
}
```

If I run the sample, I notice `Subscriber1` and `Subscriber2` are subscribed perfectly and they receive messages if I execute some of the commands in the Publisher console application. However `Subscriber3` doesn't appear to be doing anything. No exceptions are thrown and in this sample I don't seem to find any relevant log information that could lead to misconfiguration.

Has anyone tried a similar setup with ASP.NET Core & NServiceBus 6 and if so, what should I do next?

**Update 04/04/2017**

There are some updates that provide some interesting insights:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/particularsoftware/AVrA1E-VHtk
- https://particular.net/blog/nservicebus-on-net-core-why-not

Comment: I got the error while setting up NServiceBus 6.0.0.beta007 for ASP.NET core project on OSX. Unfortunately support is not good at this point but might improve after beta or maybe 7.0.0 beta version release. At this point, I'm currently using ZeroMQ for the PubSub architecture https://www.nuget.org/packages/NetMQ/4.0.0-rc5. Other person can use Redis for pubsub too using here "StackExchange.Redis" @hbulens